# jQuery carousel autoplay animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please take a look at the code below:

```js
// function scroller() {
//   $('.product:first-child').appendTo(".products-inner"); 
//  $(".products-inner").css("left","0");
//  $(".products-inner").animate({left:"-289px"},2000, "linear");
//  setTimeout("scroller()",2012); 
// };


// scroller();

// $(".prev").click(function() {
//   $('.feed-item:last-child').prependTo(".news-feed-inner"); 
//  $(".news-feed-inner").css({"top":"-150px"});
//  $(".news-feed-inner").animate({top:"0"},500);
// });

// $(".next").click(function() {
//   $('.feed-item:first-child').appendTo(".news-feed-inner"); 
//  $(".news-feed-inner").css("top","0");
//  $(".news-feed-inner").animate({top:"-150px"},500);
// });


var vox_news = 0;

$('.voxNews li').each(function() {
    vox_news += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});

$('.voxNews').parent().append($('.voxNews').clone());
  function setupNews(w) {
      function phase1() {
          var voxNews = $('.voxNews').first(),
              curMargin = voxNews.css('margin-left').replace("px", ""),
              animSpeed = (w*20) - (Math.abs(curMargin)*20);

          voxNews.animate({'margin-left' : '-' + w + 'px'}, animSpeed, 'linear', phase2);
      }
      function phase2() {
          $('.voxNews').first().css({'margin-left' : '0px'});
           phase1();
      }
      $('.voxNews img').hover(function() {
          $('.voxNews').stop();
      }, function() {
          phase1();
      });
      phase1();
  }

setupNews(vox_news);
```

```css
#news_slide{
height:150px; 
overflow:hidden;
}
.voxNews li{
margin-top:-10px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
padding:15px 0 5px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.products-outer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.products-inner {
/*   width: 1156px; */
  position: relative;
/*   left: 0px; */
/*   transition: all; */
}
.product {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="news_slide" class="products-outer">
<ul class="voxNews products-inner">
<li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-1.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-2.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-3.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-4.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-5.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-6.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-7.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-8.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hnie-assets/Promotion+Pages/100+Gifts+of+Christmas/images/product-9.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="controls">
  <button class="prev">Scroll Left</button>
  <button class="next">Scroll Right</button>
</div>
```

***CodePen: https://codepen.io/Paul34/pen/gxNKqe***

This animation supports only the forward direction.

I'd like to complete this code with both directions (forward, backward).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work. I created a reverse variable to handle when use - or + to the movement.

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul{
  float:left;
  width: 5000px;
}
```

And the JS:

```
var vox_news = 0;

$('.voxNews li').each(function() {
    vox_news += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

$('.voxNews').parent().append($('.voxNews').clone());

function setupNews(w, reverse) {
    function phase1() {
        var voxNews = $('.voxNews').first(),
            curMargin = voxNews.css('left').replace("px", ""),
            animSpeed = (w * 20) - (Math.abs(curMargin) * 20);

      if(reverse){
          voxNews.stop().animate({
              'left': w + 'px'
          }, animSpeed, 'linear', phase2);
        }else{
          voxNews.stop().animate({
              'left': '-' + w + 'px'
          }, animSpeed, 'linear', phase2);
        }
    }

    function phase2() {
        
    }
    $('.voxNews img').hover(function() {
        
    }, function() {
        phase1();
    });
    phase1();
}

setupNews(vox_news,false);

$('.prev').on('click',function(){
  setupNews(vox_news,false);
  
});
$('.next').on('click',function(){
  setupNews(vox_news,true);
  
});
```

Comment: Hi @Alvin. Thanks for your response. Direction is changed. You can see the seamless loop (forward) in the original code. So I'd like to change the code that can loop backward. Now the animation isn't looped.

Comment: Ok, that part was not in the initial question. My recommendation is to start the animation duplicating the content and set the position left to the end of the first element from your list. If you detect in the reverse movement the first element left position is 0, set the position again in the second full list of products, creating a visual loop without adding more html.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am new in this field, so could you please change your code as you said?